# How can I handover properly the value of more HTML text boxes to a MYSQL Query on the same page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

My task is to modify a MySQL record according to data from forms on a HTML page. I am browsing the Stackoverflow since yesterday morning, but I have found only solution where only one textbox is implemented. It is working. My problem is, when I want to implement more textboxes, that is not working.

This is my currently working version for a simple query with one textbox (to be easy, I do not write here the functions for SQL connection, etc):

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="button4"
class="button" value="Delete record" /><br>
<p>
<label><span>Which record do you wnat to delete?</span></label><br>
<form name="form" action="" method="POST">
<input type='number' name="delteid" id="deleteid" value="">
</form>
</p>
```

PHP:

```
//usage of buttons in php:

if(array_key_exists('button1', $_POST)) {
    button1();
}
else if(array_key_exists('button2', $_POST)) {
    button2();
}
else if(array_key_exists('button3', $_POST)) {
    button3();  
}
else if(array_key_exists('button4', $_POST)) {
    button4();  
}
```

//php function for delete:

```
function button4() {
$deleteid = $_POST['deleteid'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM list WHERE id = '$deleteid'";
}
```

I thought, I have to simple duplicate the textboxes and variables for more elements, but it is completely not working. The previously implemented delete function also not working after the modification of code with new function (maybe the new variables disturbing the old one).

The following is the not working new version:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="button3"
class="button" value="Add record" /><br>        
<br>
<p>         
<label><span>Please type the elements of new record</span><br>
<br>
<!-- <form name="form" action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="addid" id="addid" value="id">
</form>
<form name="form" action="" method="POST">
<input type='text' name="addlocation" id="addlocation" value="Location">
</form>
<form name="form" action="" method="POST">
<input type='text' name="addtype" id="addtype" value="Type">
</form>
```

PHP:

//usage of buttons in php:

```
if(array_key_exists('button1', $_POST)) {
    button1();
}
else if(array_key_exists('button2', $_POST)) {
    button2();
}
else if(array_key_exists('button3', $_POST)) {
    button3();  
}
else if(array_key_exists('button4', $_POST)) {
    button4();  
}
```

//php function for add record:

```
function button3() {
$addid = $_POST['addid'];
$addlocation = $_POST['addlocation'];
$addtype = $_POST['addtype'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO list (id, location, type) VALUES ('$addid', '$addlocation','$addtype'); ";
}
```

Could you please tell me, how can I implement the different functions properly, where I would like to receive data from more textboxes? It can be later even 9 or 10 pieces textboxes on the same page.

Thank you!

Comment: Input elements must be in the FORM, or they won't be transmitted...

Comment: the code is open to sql injection ( use prepared statements rather than directly embedding variables in the sql )

Comment: There are multiple possible outcomes depending upon which button is clicked so it is not clear how `"My task is to modify a MySQL record according to data from forms"` relates to the code shown where there is no attempt to modify a record. `"how can I implement the different functions properly"` - there is no one solution to your issue as far as I understand the question. Each form you write - be it one with a single input element or many must be handled on it's own merits and treated as such. Use [Prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: There's a typo in the input field name in your first block of HTML, `deleteid` has become `delteid`. As for the other fields, they all need to be inside the same `<form>` block, not have a separate one for each. You can see that when you debug the code using `var_dump($_POST)` before processing. Are you missing the first form open, or did you just leave it out of the question? If that doesn't help, can you expand on "not working"?